# Mockito - calling a stubbed method from non-stubbed one

Tags: mockito

Here is a very beginner's question:

The class that I mock, has methods `Map<String, Integer>methodA(String p1,String p2,String p3, SomeClass p4)` and `MyClass methodB(String p1,String p2,String p3)`

methodA internally calls methodB:

```
Map<String, Integer> methodA(String p1, String p2, String p3, SomeClass p4){
    MyClass data = methodB(p1,p2,p3);
    .... do something
    ... return Map.  
}
```

I am stubbing the methodB.

```
 when(mockedTestClass.methodB(p1, p2, p3, null)).thenReturn(myData);
```

I use null for the fourth argument since SomeClass is an abstract class.
When I call the stubbed method in the test directly with p1, p2 p3 and null (p4) arguments, it returns the correct mock data (an instance of MyClass).

However, if I call methodA, it seems that methodB is not getting called and I get empty Map (not null) returned.

What would cause this?

Thank you in advance,

Yuri.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a class you're mocking, `ClassA`, that has two methods, `method1` and `method2`. And you know that `ClassA.method1` happens to call `method2` internally. And so you've only mocked `method2`, and left `method1` with the default behavior, right?

So in that case, both methods are actually mocked, you're mocking at the class level not the method level. When you do a `when` you're saying, "I want this method to return this exact result in this specific case. If you don't use `when` then the method is an empty mock returning a null or empty value for the type that it returns. It's assumed if you don't specify you don't care.

So given that, you should see that `method1` when the class is mocked does not actually call `method2`. Both methods are mocked and only a direct call to `method2` will return the result of your `when` matcher.

Also, `when` is used to ensure a specific result is returned when a method is called. If you want to verify that a certain method was actually called with specific parameters, you can do that like this:

`verify(mockedClass).someMethod(p1, p2, p3, null); // <- or use matchers for the parameters`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It explains what I see. 
However, is there any way to achieve what I need? I need the method1 not to be mocked and actually call a mocked method2 inside, returning proper results.

Comment: Is this class with method1 and method2, the one you are trying to unit test? Because if so you are doing it wrong. When you test a class you only mock dependencies not the class itself. If you're he'll bent on this approach one idea is to refactor  method2 out to a separate class and mock just that class.